# Using TableView in JavaFX with Entity class

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding, properties, binding

I am using Hibernate for loading data from db. I have entity which looks like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    @Id@GeneratedValue@Column(name = "ID_ROLA")
    private int idRole;
    @Basic@Column(name = "NAZWA")
    private String name;
    @Basic@Column(name = "UPRAWNIENIA")
    private Integer permits;
}
```

And class RoleDAOImpl which have method like add(),search() or getListofRoles().

Now i want to bind that **Entity** class to **TableView** to show all of my Roles (I have all roles in my List< Role > roles).

**How can I add this to TableView?** 
I know that TableView should be bind to XProperties for example StringProperty.
But i don't want to do StringProperty in my Entity class, because I think it can ruin my database structure or something.

I would like to have separate class for properties.
I thought about creating **RoleTableModel** class which will contain Properties for Role class and then bind RoleTableModel class to TableView.

Is it possible? How to do this thing?

Comment: Use [`PropertyValueFactory`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html). Do note that your `TableView` would not respond to any changes to existing `Role` objects (you need to remove and re-add them).

Comment: so what can I do if i want that TableView to respond for changes automatically?

Comment: what exactly is the problem? all your entity needs are getters and setters  - then propertyValueFactory will do both reading and writing to the entity.

Comment: so when I want to create a column which will show field from entity for example idRole, I have to write only this? `idCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("idRole"));`

Comment: what happened when you tried it :) yeah, that should work. If not, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.